# How to get `texdoc changepage` to produce a result like other `texdoc package` commands?

Tags: packages, texdoc

I use `texdoc package` to view the manual for the `package` package. Normally this results in a PDF document as a sequence of pages, taking up a portion of my computer and the ability to kill the process. When I do `texdoc changepage` I get a display of two pages side-by-side overfilling the whole screen so that I cannot even kill the process.

Why is the `changepage` manual display different from all the other packages that I have recently used `texdoc` for? How can I cancel the display when it overfills the computer screen? I was the original author of `changepage`. Who changed the manual?

Comment: I get your pdf with a texlive 2022 updated today. What do you see for `texdoc -l changepage`  ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My `texlive` is 2021 (I'm waiting for the DVD) and I use the Ubuntuoperating system. `texdoc -1 changepage` returns `unknown option -1`. I tried with `texdoc -l changepage` which gave me the ability to use option `1` but got the same result as with my original `texdoc changepage`.

Comment: -l (ell not 1)  it will list all the files it found and in the order it used choosing 1will always give same result as using no option, but my question was which file is it finding?

Comment: `texdoc -l changepage` (that's ell not one) gives me `usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/doc/latex/changepage/changepage.pdf` I used `evince` to view this file and it gave me the same result as `texdoc`ing it. It still has the problem, unlike other `texdoc` files of presenting pairs of pages instead of one-by-one.

Comment: it doesn't do that for me, but I don't use evince, you must be able to change the view in the editor though, that is just an initial default hint.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, which I used. I still don't understand why the `changepage` manual should display differently from other `texdoc ...` packages. Anyway, I can now read the manual efficiently. Thank you for your help.